# Java by typing in space. InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I am currently struggling on a program by using java. The program is all good at the moment. However, I got the minor mistake. For case 1(Add item),I was tring to type the string with space in manufacturer. That occurs the Error in Eclipse like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at ass1.inventory.addItem(inventory.java:44)
at ass1.inventory.run(inventory.java:28)
at ass1.inventory.main(inventory.java:11)
```

I did a lot of research for that problem, like adding Use `in.nextLine()` instead of `in.next()`, the error still came out. Are there anyone can point out the problem for me and fix the problem? Thanks you very much!!

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inventory {

private static item[] inventory;
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
private static int noOfItems;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    noOfItems=0;        
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inventory=new item[5];
    run();      
}
public static int displayMenu()
{
    System.out.println("1.Add a product");
    System.out.println("2.Display a product");
    System.out.println("3.Quit");
    int i=scanner.nextInt();
    return i;   
}
public static void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int i=displayMenu();
        switch(i)
        {
        case 1:addItem();
                break;
        case 2:findItem();
                break;
        case 3:return;
        default:System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
}
public static void addItem()
{
    System.out.print("Enter Item name:");
    String item_name=scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the manufacturer:");
    String manufacturer=scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Enter price:");
    double price=scanner.nextDouble();

    item b=new item(item_name,manufacturer,price);
    if(noOfItems==inventory.length)
        System.out.println("Array is full");
    else
    {
        inventory[noOfItems++]=b;
        System.out.println("Item added successfully");
    }
}   
public static void findItem()
{
    System.out.print("Enter item name:");
    String item_name=scanner.next();
    for(int i=0; i<noOfItems; i++)
    {
        if(item_name(inventory[i].getItem_name()))
        {
            System.out.println("Item found:");
            System.out.print(inventory[i]+"\n");
            return;
        }                           
    }       
}
}
```

This is another file connect to first one:

```
public class item {

  private String item_name;
  private String manufacturer;
  private double price;

  //To initialise the state of the object
  public item(String item_name,String manufacturer,double price)
  {
    this.item_name=item_name;
    this.manufacturer=manufacturer;
    this.price=price;
  }
  //Reader methods i.e behavior methods
  public String getItem_name()
  {
    return item_name;
  }
  public String getManufacturer()
  {
    return manufacturer;
  }
  public double getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }
  //Writer methods or setter methods  public void setTitle(String item_name)
  {
    this.item_name=item_name;
  }
  public void setManufact(String manufacturer)
  {
    this.manufacturer=manufacturer;
  }
  public void setPrice(double price)
  {
    if(price < 0)
      System.out.println("Price cannot be negative");
    else
      this.price=price;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Item name:"+item_name+"\nManufacturer:"+manufacturer+"\nPrice:"+price;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in many ways

Try adding `scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` at the beginning of `additem` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because `scanner.next()` only reads in the next token before a space.

Now if I were to run your code, with a bit of modification to display the values. Like below.

```
System.out.print("Enter Item name:");
String item_name = scanner.next();
System.out.print("Enter the manufacturer:");
String manufacturer = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Manufacturer:" + manufacturer); //Print Manufacturer
System.out.print("Enter price:");
double price = scanner.nextDouble();
```

And if I were to write `test test` as input for manufacturer, only `test` will be assigned the variable manufacturer. Leaving the remaining string in the buffer. Like the result below.

```
Enter Item name:test
Enter the manufacturer:test test
Manufacturer:test
Enter price:Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at stackOverflowQns.inventory.addItem(inventory.java:50)
    at stackOverflowQns.inventory.run(inventory.java:32)
    at stackOverflowQns.inventory.main(inventory.java:15)
```

You mentioned using `scanner.nextLine()` doesn't work. Here is why.

Since you've used methods such as `scanner.next()`, `scanner.nextInt()`, etc. All these method will leave line separator (`\n`) in the buffer. Therefore, when you call `scanner.nextLine()` subsequently, it will pick up whatever that is before the line separator and return you empty strings. And that's where you see things like this.

```
Enter Item name:test
Enter the manufacturer:Enter price:
```

Therefore to resolve your issue,
You have to either do a `scanner.nextLine()` before reading the value from the user, just to clear the line separator. Like below. But this is just ugly, which I don't recommend.

```
System.out.print("Enter the manufacturer:");
scanner.nextLine();
String manufacturer = scanner.nextLine();
```

Or do as what the other answer proposed, which is to set to only use the line separator as the delimiter, hence, resolving all the mentioned issues.